# check if radiobutton is selected on different/other page with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, radio-button

I have two pages `view.phtml` and `detail.phtml`. The content of `detail.phtml` is included/loaded in `view.phtml`. I have radiobuttons in `view.phtml`. If I select a radiobutton, I want to show a picture ([see Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/YK3wN/2/))
My Problem now is, that the `<div id="hS" class="haekchen"></div><p>Choose an option</p>` part is in `detail.phtml` and the radiobuttons are in `view.phtml`.

Now I want to show the picture in `detail.phtml`, if a radiobutton in `view.phtml` is selected.

Would this be the right call to get the radiobuttons from view.phtml ? `jQuery('#options').load('ajax/view.phtml');` How can I process the data, if that call wouldn't be entirely wrong?

Comment: Depends on the way the content is loaded from one page to another. If you are using something like `include("detail.phtml")` in PHP or similar, then you should be able to select elements from `detail.phtml` as if it were part of the current page. Even if you load the other page dynamically, like with AJAX, you still should be able to just select the elements there normally, by ID or class.

Comment: ok I think I got it. I also forgot to close a  brace at one point, so it couldn't work at all. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

view.phtml:

```
<div id="container" ></div>
<label><input id="option1" type="radio" name="dressing" value="Dressing">Option 1</label>
<label><input id="option2" type="radio" name="dressing" value="Dressing">Option 2</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#container').load('detail.phtml');
        $('#option1').on('change', function(){
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $('#hS').fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });
        $('#option2').on('change', function(){
            if ($("#option2").is(":checked")) {
                $('#hS').fadeOut('slow');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

detail.phtml:

```
<div id="hS" class="haekchen" hidden ></div><p>Choose an option</p>
```